# How to identify ARM board programmatically

Tags: arm, raspberry-pi, beagleboneblack, iot

Is there a way how to programmatically identify which arm board I'm currently running on? Either raspberry pi, cubieboard, or beagleboneblack? These 3 types are enough to differentiate. 
I was hoping to use `cat /sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id/sys_vendor` but this is not available on ARM ports of debian :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my board, in /proc/cpuinfo, I've got

```
Processor       : ARMv7 Processor rev 7 (v7l)
processor       : 0
BogoMIPS        : 1562.98

processor       : 1
BogoMIPS        : 1560.01

Features        : swp half thumb fastmult vfp edsp thumbee neon vfpv3 tls 
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant     : 0x2
CPU part        : 0xc09
CPU revision    : 7

Hardware        : FC7100 Workbench
Revision        : 6008
```

The interesting part is the `Hardware` field, which is the name of my board. This field is based on the machine id, from the arch/arm/tools/mach-type linux file. Nevertheless, this approach may be outdated now, as we now use device trees instead of board support packages. You may have to look for Device Tree documentation to get the information you need.

Answer (score 4):

You can read the [`MIDR`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0500f/BABFEABI.html) register which will provide implementer, variant, architecutre, partnum, and revision that you might help to distinguish the boards on which you're running your code.

You can get that register using `MRC p15, 0, <Rt>, c0, c0, 0`

Reference: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0500f/BABFEABI.html

Comment: I don't see how this addresses the question. A _board_ is far more than just the CPU core, or even the SoC. Besides, consider that the Allwinner A10 on the Cubieboard has Cortex-A8 r3p2, whereas the TI AM3359 on the BeagleBone Black has, er, Cortex-A8 r3p2...

Comment: that's right, indeed. I have not checked which board uses which CPU, it was just a hint, of a possible way to find out information. In the case of the cubie and beagle, it seems that it doesn't fit. Oops :)
Thanks for noticing this!

Answer (score 0):

I write in Python.
I look at /proc/cpuinfo and parse out the Hardware field.
BCM2708 is a Pi1 (A, B, A+,B+)
BCM2709 is a Pi2 (B+)
BCM2835 is a Pi3

For Beaglebone you can:

```
import platform
p = platform.platform()
```

If any of these are true, you have a Beaglebone Black.

```
if p.lower().find('arm7l-with-debian') > -1
if p.lower().find('arm7l-with-ubuntu') > -1
if p.lower().find('arm7l-with-glibc2.4') > -1
if p.lower().find('arm7l-with-arch') > -1
```

If it's not RPi and not Beaglebone then perhaps it is the other.

This was gleaned from work done by Tony DiCola at Adafruit but I don't recall from what project I found it in.